# create a specific query with querybuilder in symfony

Tags: doctrine, repository, symfony, query-builder, dql

i'm developing an application with symfony 3 and i want to create a custom query with query builder.

 i have an entity named: Bien having many adresses.( Address is an other entity). so i want to get all adresses not existing in Bien entity.

the query that i want to produce is :
 `select a.id from address a where a.id not in ( select b.address_id from bien b)`

in my AddressRepository i did that :

```
public function getAdressesByRueNotJoined($rue)
    {
        $qb2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('ab')
            ->from('BienBundle:Bien', 'bi');
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

        return
            $qb->where('a.rue = :rue')
                ->setParameter('rue', $rue)
                ->andWhere(
                    $qb->expr()->notIn('a', $qb2->getDQL())
                )
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
    }
```

the query returned is :

> SELECT a0_.id AS id_0, a0_.name AS name_1, a0_.rue_id AS rue_id_2 FROM
>   adresse a0_ WHERE a0_.rue_id = ? AND a0_.id NOT IN (SELECT a1_.id FROM
>   adresse a1_, bien b2_)

How can i resolve that ?

Comment: I would advise you to see the Mawcel answer to understand how you have to structure your query. Try to mix his query with the `notIn()` condition from the doctrine docs : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in $qb2  i added identiy like this

```
$qb2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('ad')
            ->from('SBC\BienBundle\Entity\Bien', 'bi')
            ->select('IDENTITY(bi.address)');
```

but i dont what does it mean

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your whole request is wrong, you should be using a join to query your Biens by Rue if Bien has a oneToMany relationship with Adresse

```
$qb = $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('b')
    ->select('b.id')
    ->from('BienBundle:Bien b')
    ->leftJoin('b.addresses' 'a' )
    ->where('a.rue = :rue')
    ->setParameter('rue', $rue)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```